# First order aproximation of the wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

In Griffith's "Introduction to QM", while studying time independent perturbation theory, I read that the first order aproximated wave function can be written as $\sum_{m\neq n} c_m^{(n)}\psi_{m}^{0}$, because the solutions to the Schroedinger equation $H^{0}\psi_n^{0}=E^0\psi_n^0$ constitute a complete set of functions. But I wonder why the case m=n can be excluded, could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that is the first order correction. If you include the zeroth order correction you'd get
\begin{equation}
\psi_n = \psi_n^0 + \sum_{m \neq n} c_m^{(n)} \psi_m^0 + \dots,
\end{equation}
where, if perturbation theory holds, $|c_m^{(n)}| \ll 1$.
Let me know if this answered your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The book said that even if $\psi_n^1$ had some $\psi_n^0$ component in it, it would be possible to take it out, thus considering a sum where $m \neq n$. I don't understand why this can be done

Comment: I think what they mean is that you can redefine your "free" Hamiltonian such that the interacting Hamiltonian only gives non-diagonal corrections to the eigenfunctions. I don't know what is the precise problem, but why don't you consider the sum over $m=n$ as well and explicitly see if you get some inconsistency with it? I doubt you won't. It's just a matter of redefining your free Hamiltonian, I'm guessing.

Comment: I tried to consider the case where m=n, but I didn't find anything that allows me to take $c_n=0$, because the sums in which $c_m$ is involved are 0 for the case $m=n$, whatever is the value of $c_n$

Comment: Think about this geometrically in terms of vectors. If there is a contribution proportional to $\psi_n^0$ all it is doing is stretching your original vector. At some point, however, you are going to normalize this thing, in which case all the $\psi_n^0$ contribution is going to do is rescale the other $c_m^{(n)}$s. But in that case we can just take that into account from the start and not worry about the $\psi_n^0$ contribution.